# How can I handle application startup without using default form mybase.load

Tags: vb.net, handler, startup

I am having trouble figuring out how to run code on application startup.  The scenario is, I need to check if a user setting exists, if it does not, then I need to open a company configuration form.  I tried creating a module to store application level events, but get an error:

BC31418 Visual Basic AND  VB.NET in modules must specify a 'WithEvents' variable qualified with a single identifier.

```
Module ApplicationEvents

    Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        If My.Settings.xmlpath = "" Then
            Dim f As New CompanySetup()
            f.ShowDialog()
            f.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

I really do not want to put the IF statement into the default form mybase.load handler, since this application is in early stages, and the default form may change, leading me to have to move this code around.  Any help on this error, or suggestions of how to get the IF statement to occur on application startup without tying it into a sub on the default form would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rather than explicitly calling `Dispose`, creating the form with a `Using` statement. It will then be implicitly disposed at the `End Using` statement. Do that with all disposable objects that you only use within one block.

Comment: On a stylistic note, your setting will become properties so you should name them as you would any other property, e.g. `XmlPath` rather than `xmlpath`.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of that module. Open the Application page of the project properties and click the *View Application Events* button.  That will open the proper code file in which to create a `Startup` event handler.  You can do that using the second and third drop-downs in the Navigation Bar at the top of the code window.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!